# Better way for coding the subscriptions in CKRecord extension?

Tags: swift, struct, enums, protocols, cloudkit

```
extension CKRecord {
    subscription (key: Name) -> Any? {
      get { return self[key.rawValue] }
      set { self[key.rawValue] = newValue as? CKRecordValue }
    }
}

enum Name { case first, last, middle, nick }
```

// case names are field names in Name ckrecord type

The above works for my purpose but I have 66 CKRecord Types (e.g. Name, Address, ...). Does that mean I have to write: subscriptioin (key: Address) ..., then the next, 66 times!!!  Is there a better way to organize my code to this matter?  I'm thinking of putting all such enums to a struct...is it a right direction?

Comment: What are some of your other record types? If you have 66, then I wonder if you are using record types when you should be relying more on multiple **fields** within record types in CloudKit. Fewer record types will make managing your subscriptions a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks Clifton for your comment. Fewer record types are possible and due to normalizing many-many relationships there will be still at least dozens of record types left.  Do your comment imply no better way than writing one subscription to match each record type?

Comment: CloudKit subscriptions always have to be associated with a single record type, yes. Can you list 10-20 of your "record types" so I can get a better sense for what you are trying to do? Your example of `Name`, `Address`, etc. implies you should have a `Person` (or similar) record type with `name` and `address` **fields**. I'm having trouble believing your data is so discrete that you need so many record types. :)

Comment: Maybe you're already aware, but a "record type" in CloudKit is similar to a "table" in SQL. Each **record type** (`table`) can have many different **fields** (`columns`).

Comment: Yes, I have Person, Employee, Vendor, Client, Currency, ExchangeRate, Benefit, Allowance, Entitlement, Phone, Email, Ledger, Journal, Device... to name a few basic. Plus some relationship types/tables to normalize many to many. Well, I don't mind to copy-paste subscription block and change its name to each record type, but it is hard to manage changes with these many subscriptions.  I am looking into protocol and functional programming but need some expert to shed me a light to lead a right direction.